# redirect from one grid to another with parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have grid in view. after selecting row and then click to redirect button, which redirects me to another view grid, filtered from first grid parentID. first comes in second views action (Index(int parentID)) and it works parentID is not null, but page refreshed and comes to grid's read action ant there parentid is null

what is it refreshing twice in time? I don't want parentID to be null

Comment: We cant guess what you might be doing wrong - you need to show your code!

Answer (score 0):

Use TempData for send the parentid value to the grid's read view page and assign the value in a hidden field.Hope it will help.